# GCM for chrome 403 forbbiden error

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-messaging

We make chrome extension with gcm for chrome. We get Oauth like "ya29.****" and put this extension to develop dashboard.

Our server request to send message to gcm and got this error.

Why dose gcm for chrome return this error?

```
{
"error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "gcmForChrome.message",
            "reason": "forbiddenForNonAppOwner",
            "message": "A message can only be sent by the owner of the app."
        }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "A message can only be sent by the owner of the app."
}
```

Our server request is like this.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.googleapis.com/gcm_for_chrome/v1/messages');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($arr));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you **publish** the extension? It must be pubilshed (you can publish to trusted testers) before you can send push messages. Uploading it to the developer dashboard is not enough.

Also make sure the extension ids on Chrome Web Store and on your computer are consistent (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cloudMessaging.html#test-cloud).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but we can't publish because of this error.
[link](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/pkmiFvCypks)